# Questions about the extended real number system.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am currently reading Rudin's real analysis and in chapter $1$ definition $1.23$ he introduced the extended real number system $\mathbb{\bar{R}}=\mathbb{R} \cup \{ -\infty , \infty \} $ his definition raised a lot of questions in my mind, such as: How is this useful at all? I can see that any sequence of real numbers has a "convergent" subsequence in this system, $\infty , -\infty $ mean in this case ? Rudin refer to them as numbers (in definition 3.16 for example ) then what is even a number? how to define what is a "number" in this case? another question that came to mind is how many "number" that belong to the extended real number system that don't belong to $\mathbb{R}$ in other words is $|\mathbb{\bar{R}}|=|\mathbb{R}|$? the definition of extended real number suggest that $\mathbb{\bar{R}}$ has only two "numbers" more than $\mathbb{R}$ but does that mean any two infinite digit "numbers" are equivalent ? for example does $\dots 11111111= \dots 1212121121212$ ?  if they are equal then what does equal means in the new real number system?   another question is why $\frac{x}{\infty} =0$ in this system. in other words does the number $10000000 \dots$ have an inverse that is $0.0000 \dots 000001$ which is the infinitesimal?

another question is if $|\mathbb{\bar{R}}|>|\mathbb{R}|$ does than mean $|\mathbb{\bar{R}}|=|\aleph_2|$? or $|\mathbb{\bar{R}}|$ is even bigger than that

Comment: $-\infty$ and $\infty$ are just abstract symbols and the order on $\overline {\mathbb R}$ makes them behave as we intuitively expect it to. And as you say, since every sequence has a monotone subsequence, every real sequence has a subsequence that converges in $\overline {\mathbb R}$. That $x \cdot \infty = \infty$ for $x > 0$ and $x/\infty = 0$ and so on are just convention based on how we *want* arithmetic with $\pm \infty$ to behave. The definition of $\overline {\mathbb R}$ gives no meaning to "infinite-digit number".

Comment: though of course $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty 10^n = \infty$ still. I can't say you should understand this as $111111 \ldots = \infty$. If you do, then $1/(11111 \ldots)$ is just $0$.

Comment: @GeorgeCoote why the infinitesimal  is not in that system ?

Comment: @GeorgeCoote I thought this new system is only useful because that any sequence of real numbers has a "convergent" subsequence in this system like $1,11,111,1111,11111...$ are sequence of real number so the limit must be in the extended real number sysytem

Comment: @pie there is a version of calculus that includes infinitesimal as pretty normal numbers, which can be used with arithmetics, but it's way more difficult then this. Arithmetic on $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is not well defined in general, $\pm \infty$ is mostly useful to speak about limits, I would even say that writing $1 + \infty$ is usually not a good idea.

Comment: @pie there is no notion of infinitesimal, $1/\infty$ is defined to be literally $0$ rather than an arbitrarily small quantity. I don't think it means much to have infinitely many $0$s then a $1$ on the end.

Comment: let me say that the cardinality of the extended real line is the same as the cardinality of the standard real line. So, yes, $|\mathbb{\bar{R}}|=|\mathbb{R}|$. This cardinality is usually called just the cardinality of the continuum $\mathfrak{c}$. it cannot be assigned an aleph number without additional set theoretic axioms, it could be almost any aleph number, and in particular you should not go around assuming that $|\mathbb{R}|=\aleph_1$ but it does have a beth number, $\beth_1$. In general adding finitely many elements to an infinite set does not change the cardinality.

Comment: @pie, with regard to your question concerning $\frac{x}{\infty}$: assuming that this is zero is merely a convenient convention.  If one substitutes an infinite number for $\infty$ in this fraction in an ordered field properly extending $\mathbb R$, one would indeed get a nonzero infinitesimal (if $x$ is finite).

Comment: @ziggurism is right. In fact, if you don't assume at least a weak version of the axiom of choice, you can't even prove $\beth_1$ is an aleph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extending $\mathbb R$ by adding an extra point at either end is just a convenient tool for formulating certain theorems that would be too bulky if one had to treat the case when certain expressions diverge to infinity.  These extra points $\infty$ and $-\infty$ are referred to as "numbers" only metaphorically.  You can't have infinitesimals in such a system.  If you are interested in number systems with infinitesimals, you could consult *questions* under the tags [infinitesimals](/questions/tagged/infinitesimals) and [nonstandard-analysis](/questions/tagged/nonstandard-analysis).

With regard to your question comparing $\bar{\mathbb R}$ with cardinalities $\aleph_i$, you should keep in mind that infinite numbers in infinitesimal analysis are not the same as cardinalities, and should not be confused with them.